# How to change statusbar and navigation bar color in JetpackCompose App?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to change status bar and naviagtion bar color in my app by default it is not set.
This is my composeable AppTheme function where I have to change in.

```
val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }
```

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primaryContainer = Color.Black,
    onPrimaryContainer = Color.White
)
private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = RoyalBlue,
    primaryContainer = RoyalBlue,
    onPrimaryContainer = Color.White
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line in your AppTheme Composable Function:

```
window.statusBarColor = if (darkTheme)  Color.Black.toArgb() else RoyalBlue.toArgb()
```

here change the color according to your dark and light colors.

Also to change the navigation bar color add these lines of code in AppTheme composable:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
if (darkTheme) {
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Black
    )
} else {
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = RoyalBlue
    )
}
```

Change the colors accordingly of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

**The use val `systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()` is deprecated :** https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/

Use custom method or try with  "androidx.activity:activity" library **v1.8.0-rc01** in your activity. Do something like this :

```
 enableEdgeToEdge(
                statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb(),
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb()
                ),
                navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb(),
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb()
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines to Theme.kt after initializing the **window** variable:

```
window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
```

In the end you will get something like this:

```
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
        window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).